# Error in Upsert via Dataloader Batch

Tags: batch, integration, dataloader-batch

attempting to run the bat displays this error

```
C:\Users\admsp-kelly\dataloader\v45.0.0\bin>process.bat 

"C:\BatchsPF\Protocolos\
conf" accountUpdate
2019-04-05 16:42:23,518 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.j
ava:473) - Using built-in logging configuration, no log-conf.xml in C:\Users\adm
sp-kelly\dataloader\v45.0.0\bin\configs\log-conf.xml
2019-04-05 16:42:23,546 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.j
ava:475) - The log has been initialized
2019-04-05 16:42:23,548 INFO  [main] process.ProcessConfig getBeanFactory (Proce
ssConfig.java:104) - Loading process configuration from config file: C:\BatchsPF
\Protocolos\conf\process-conf.xml
2019-04-05 16:42:23,650 INFO  [main] support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareR
efresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:495) - Refreshing org.springframework.co
ntext.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@6f3b5d16: startup date [Fri Apr 05
 16:42:23 BRT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-04-05 16:42:23,705 INFO  [main] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinit
ions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315) - Loading XML bean definitions from file
 [C:\BatchsPF\Protocolos\conf\process-conf.xml]
2019-04-05 16:42:23,772 INFO  [main] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInsta
ntiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557) - Pre-instantiating singl
etons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@29
25bf5b: defining beans [accountUpdate]; root of factory hierarchy
2019-04-05 16:42:23,843 ERROR [accountUpdate] controller.Controller <init> (Cont
roller.java:125) - Exception happened in initConfig:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5614)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getConfigDirFromArgMa
p(Controller.java:133)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.jav
a:123)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getInstance(Controlle
r.java:269)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.jav
a:117)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.jav
a:107)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.ja
va:266)
2019-04-05 16:42:23,854 FATAL [accountUpdate] process.ProcessRunner topLevelErro
r (ProcessRunner.java:251) - Unable to run process accountUpdate
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5614)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getConfigDirFromArgMa
p(Controller.java:133)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.jav
a:123)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getInstance(Controlle
r.java:269)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.jav
a:117)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.jav
a:107)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.ja
va:266)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue was fixed in the new release drop. Try updating and see if that solves your error.

https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/179

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pan4QAA